# Custom job and site enumeration error

Tags: custom-timer-job

I have a WebPart where I'm executing a custom job. For most users it works fine but for some not, and in log I can see such an entry:

> site enumeration stack at
>   microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsitecollection.get_item(int32
>   index)

Here is the implementation of Execute method:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
            SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;          

            SPList myList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["myList"];
            ...
//operations on that list, updates too
}
```

Under what account is that job executed? Could it be the problem that some users do not have privileges and even webApp.Sites[0] could not be evaluated?

Comment: I have to mention I know, that timer service works on farm account (owstimer.exe) and I also know that RunWithElevatedPrivileges probably will have no result here

Comment: How does your web part execute the job?